# Showing Tikz tree nodes after each other (using bracketing format of \Tree)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, overlays, tikz-qtree

I want to display a tikz tree node by node.
First A, then A and B and in the end all nodes.
Note that I need to do it with the presented format:

```
\Tree
[. \node{A};]
```

since trees are automatically generated in this format and I want to only modify them not to destroy.
I tried putting a subtree in \visible<>{} but no success.
If I use [opacity=0] for a node then arcs are still visible.
How to make a subtree invisible?  that's would really solve my problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<4>{}
%\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down]
    \tikzset{level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 10pt}
    \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
    \Tree
      [. \node{A};
        [. \node{B};
          [. \node{C};]
        ]
      ]     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Too bad you are not using `forest`! I also have code to do this in `qtree` but both of those packages use the standard bracket notation which you are not using. (That is, you have `[. \node{A};]` rather than `[{A}]` or `[.{A}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option using the `visible on` style and `\edge` operation to have control over the edges, allowing to stepwise reveal them:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} 
  },
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=down]
    \tikzset{level distance = 25pt, sibling distance = 10pt}
    \tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
    \Tree
      [. \node[visible on=<1->]{A};\edge[visible on=<2->];
        [. \node[visible on=<2->]{B};\edge[visible on=<3->];
          [. \node[visible on=<3>]{C};]
        ]
      ]     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```